# Can one Domain address point to IPaddress/~username not just pain IP address

Tags: unix, dns, ip

I have just one IP address for my server. It has two websites
123.456.789.11/~user1
123.456.789.11/~user2

Can I have two domains pointing to each user separately?
www.domainabc.com --> 123.456.789.11/~user1
www.domainxyz.com --> 123.456.789.11/~user2

I do not wish to append any thing to either of the domain names [ www.domainabc.com/~bigNO ]

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DNS is only concerned with mapping names to IP addresses. It knows nothing about protoocols, or anything else outside of the name `www.example.com` or the address `123.45.67.89`

Most, if not all, web servers understand the concept of a virtual host, so you could configure user1.example.com to be a specific virtual host that then redirects to www.example.com/user1